# Linux : How to get out of the linux filesystem repair prompt by repairing the filesystem

Tags: linux, filesystems

When I try to log into my FC16 VM, I end up on the Filesystem repair prompt.

I am guessing this is an issue caused by the corruption of the filesystem.

In this filesystem repair prompt, I am unable to run most of the commands. Most of the files are also in read only mode.

First thing is that I want to know the type of my Filesystem - is it ext2, ext3 or ext4??

For that if I do a "df -T", it says that it doesn't recognise df command.

If I simply run fsck, this is all I get:

(Repair filesystem):# fsck
fsck from util linux 2.20.1
(Repair filesystem):#

Upon reboot I end at the same repair filesystem prompt again.

What is the way out of here??What are the commands that I can run here in the repair filesystem prompt?

TIA - 
Sidharth

Comment: I think this queation better fits into superuser.com.

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/472205/how-to-get-out-of-the-linux-filesystem-repair-prompt-after-repairing-the-filesys

Comment: Celada, I was asked to move it to superuser.com...so I only posted this one there. Any pointers?? TIA